# C++ Each Class method in a separate file?

Tags: c++, class, compilation

What would be the best and/or more standard way to put each Class' method in a separate file?

For instance:

```
Class A {
    public:
        void method_a(int foo1);
        void method_b(int foo2);
}
```

Putting the code of method_a() and method_b() in separate .cpp files, although both end up belonging to Class A.

How should the #includes and headers be organized?

The idea is to keep files small for fast partial compilation (by hand not IDE). So just compile the file and then link to the others already compiled.

Comment: Generally you have 1 `.cpp` file and one `.h` file for each entire class. So unless there would be tons of methods, they generally would all go in one `.cpp` file.

Comment: There will be around 15-20 methods but all with quite large amount of code. So compiling everything just for a small change in one method wastes a lot of time.

Comment: @Davinish - define 'quite large amount of code'. How much time do you aim to save by managing 16-21 files instead of just 2?

Comment: Compiling takes time... and so does keeping 15-20 files (or more, per class!) organized.  It takes time to open, close, and navigate them.  This is a bad idea.

Comment: @enhzflep Is a Class that is modified very often and takes around 5 minutes to compile. So summing up all small changes compilations can waste in a day an hour or two that could be used in much more productive ways.

Comment: @Ed S. is it even possible? so I can decide in which cases it would be useful.

Comment: @Davinish: Sure, it's possible.  You could easily try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header file foo.h

```
Class A {
    public:
        void method_a(int foo1);
        void method_b(int foo2);
};
```

in fooa.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
void A::method_a(int foo1)
{ 
    // blah blah
}
```

in foob.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
void A::method_b(int foo2)
{ 
    // blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll begin by elaborating on this :

> So just compile the file and then link to the others already compiled.

What if altering an implementation file (.cpp) requires a change in the header (eg change the arguments passed in a member function) ? Then the header would change and all .cpp files that include that header would require recompilation.

The success of the compilation method you propose has (at least) **three measures :**

- success in terms of **compilation speed**
- **size** of object files and
- **ease of use** (for an IDE it would be far easier to roam around a plethora of files compared to plain VI), especially considering how would this method scale with an evolving/growing project.

All of them heavily depend on the **toolchain** you use for creating / compiling your projects and its **configurations / optimization settings**. Two things are **guaranteed** (and obvious FWIW) :

- It is a correct process of work, allowed by the language.
- It's **not that oftenly seen**.

The later fact can be justified considering the existence of **dedicated tools that speed up** your compilation. I'll mention two :

- The [ninja](http://aosabook.org/en/posa/ninja.html) build system
- Correct use of [precompiled headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx) in Visual studio